# Url rewrite using htaccess change query string in base url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove string from the end of URL:

For example i have a structure like this:

```
http://sitename.com/category/first-category-name.php/?post_type=question
http://sitename.com/category/second-category-name.php/?post_type=question
http://sitename.com/category/...-category-name.php/?post_type=question
```

I would like to convert url from `http://sitename.com/category/-----category-name/?post_type=question to http://sitename.com/category/-----category-name/post_type/question` from the end of URL.

Comment: -1 You have indicated below that you would like to redirect using .htaccess rather than php. Therefore this question has nothing to do with php.

Comment: You'd probably what to do that with an .htaccess file: See ModRewrite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally redirect if the `post_type` value exists in the query string.

```
// Get the category. This is here for example purposes.
$categoryName = 'first-category-name';

if (!empty($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $postType = $_GET['post_type'];
    header("Location: http://sitename.com/category/$categoryName/post_type/$postType", true, 301);
}
```

For security, you probably want to make sure `$category` and `$postType` are sanitized.

Comment: Thanks for replay but I don't  want to redirect the URL I just want to rewrite the URL

LIKE

** RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L] **

Comment: In this context, rewriting is the "same" as redirecting. If you're trying to rewrite the URL without using PHP, then this question has nothing to do with PHP (i.e. please remove PHP from the tags of this question).